# Variable as array value

Tags: angularjs, multidimensional-array

I have this array

```
$scope.critere_cuisine = [
    {"name" : "Assiettes plates",
    "etats" : $scope.etats
  }]
```

which refers to

```
$scope.etats = [{ "text": "Bon", "checked": true },
  { "text": "Moyen", "checked": false },
  { "text": "Mauvais", "checked": false }];
```

But i don't manage to make it work, where am i wrong ?

Comment: Where you are wrong is that you haven't told us what it means to you to 'make it work', nor have you shown any of the code where you attempted to use the data structures you created.

Comment: what about it doesn't work?  are you getting an error?

Comment: when i do console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.critere_cuisine)) i get [{"name":"Assiettes plates","etats":""}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably defined `etats` below `critere_cuisine`. If you declare `etats` before `critere_cuisine` it should work fine.

Comment: It's no problem. Everybody has these moments. Good luck!